# Call from mobile using Asterisk VoIP Line

Tags: android, windows-phone-8.1, asterisk, voip

It is possible to make a call from my mobile (which will be into the same LAN with Asterisk) and use the Asterisk VoIP line? and not my mobile phone line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need install sip softphone on your device

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.europesip.asteriskconnect

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoiper.android.app

www.zoiper.com for softphone on computer

Good luck